# How to use context in different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my private route component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, createContext } from "react";
import Header from "../../components/common/Header/container";
import { Outlet, useNavigate, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

const PrivateRoute=({ fetchMe })=> {
  const [type, setType] = useState("sports_keymoments");
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
  const [lodar, setLodar] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ name: "Ashish" });
  const { Provider } = createContext('user');

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <>
      <Provider user={user}>
        {lodar && <Spin indicator={antIcon} className="loader__full" />}
        <Header type={type} setType={setType} />
        <Outlet context={[type, setType]} />
      </Provider>
    </>
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" />
  );
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

Now I need to use `user` context in the Header and the `outlet` component. For that I did this

```
const theme = useContext("user");
console.log({theme})
```

But I am getting undefined in the `theme`. Kindly help with this.

Comment: Hey friend, I recommend you to utilize a tool called `recoil.js`, then you are going to have more control on the project flexibility and scalability. It's as easy as using `react.js` `context` API but something more better. BTW if you don't wanna use that you can follow @Olivier's answer

Answer (score 2):

You should write `<Provider value={user}>` instead of `<Provider user={user}>`

[Context.Provider documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider)

You should give a look at the [useContext documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

First create the context ouside of your component and export it

```js
export const UserContext = React.createContext({name: ""});
```

In your App component :

```js
<UserContext.Provider value={user}>
```

In your children components :

```js
import {UserContext} from "..."

const user = useContext(UserContext);
console.log(user.name);
```

Comment: and how can I use it in Outlet?

Comment: the same way as in the Header component (i.e. by using `useContext`)

Comment: still getting `undefined`. This line is correct `const { Provider } = createContext('user');`?

Comment: I updated my answer, you didn't use the context correctly, you must create it outside of your component and use it in your children component

Answer (score 1):

When using context you create it outside of your react component, then use it.
Example files:

- contextNews.js (Your context file)
- ProviderWrapper.js (The wrapper for the react components which will consume your context)
- componentUsesContext.js (An example component using the context)

**contextNews.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// This can be whatever you want. Just an example.
const placeholder = {
  dataNews: {
    title: '',
  },
  setDataNews: () => {},
};

export const ContextNews = React.createContext(placeholder);

export const ProviderNews: React = ({ children, dataNewsDefault = {}}) => {
  const [dataNews, setDataNews] = useState(dataNewsDefault);

  return (
    <ContextNews.Provider
      value={{
        dataNews,
        setDataNews
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ContextNews.Provider>
  );
};
```

**ProviderWrapper.js**

```js
import {ProviderNews} from './contextNews'
import ComponentUsesContext from './ComponentUsesContext'
// You must provider a wrapper
// You cannot access context here.
const Wrapper = () => {
   <ProviderNews> {/* your components that will share context go here...*/}
      <ComponentUsesContext/> 
   </ProviderNews>
}
```

**ComponentUsesContext.js**

```js
import {ContextNews} from './contextNews'

const Comp = () => {
  // have access to properties of the context now...
  const {dataNews, setDataNews} = React.useContext(contextNews)
  return null; // whatever you want...
}
```